# SQL Server 2008 R2: Optimizing query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization, for-xml-path

I am running into some performance issues when running a relatively simple query. The situation is as follows:

I have a table, lets name it `[Old_Table]` which is set up like this:

```
Document ID  | Parsed_Codes
-------------+-------------
Document_1   |  a
Document_1   |  b
Document_1   |  c
Document_2   |  a
Document_2   |  d
Document_3   |  a
Document_3   |  c
```

This table has a total of 2.5 million rows and roughly 500k unique `[Document ID]` values.

What I want to do is aggregate this table into a new table named `[New_Table]` which should look like this:

```
Document ID  | New_Parsed_Codes
-------------+-----------------
Document_1   |  a; b; c
Document_2   |  a; d
Document_3   |  a; c
```

In order to do so I have created the following query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.[Document ID] as [Document ID],
    Stuff((SELECT '; ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), Parsed_Codes)
           FROM dbo.[Old_Table] t2
           WHERE t2.[Document ID] = t1.[Document ID]
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as [New_Parsed_Codes]
INTO dbo.[New_Table]
FROM dbo.[Old_Table] t1
GROUP BY t1.[Document ID]
```

The problem now is that these numbers don't appear to be too large, yet the query easily takes between 16 and 32 hours to complete. The machine I am running this on has 120GB RAM and 24 Cores.

The question now is; is there any way to alter the query to make it more efficient. Or maybe there is a different method all together

Comment: How big is the table 'byte-wise' ? (e.g. the result of the data column of sp_spaceused). From the example I 'deduce' we're talking about 2.5M rows of about say 40 bytes each, giving less than 100Mb of (relevant) data. I'm assuming you simplified the example ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to perform `group_concat` is using `cross apply` instead of `correlated subquery`. Try this.

```
SELECT t1.[Document ID] AS [Document ID],
LEFT(cs.New_Parsed_Codes, Len(cs.New_Parsed_Codes) - 1) AS New_Parsed_Codes
FROM   Old_Table t1
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT '; ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), Parsed_Codes)
                    FROM   dbo.[Old_Table] t2
                    WHERE  t2.[Document ID] = t1.[Document ID]
                    FOR XML PATH('')) cs ([New_Parsed_Codes])
GROUP  BY t1.[Document ID],
          LEFT(cs.New_Parsed_Codes, Len(cs.New_Parsed_Codes) - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am currently running the query and will let you know if it improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

As the numbers involved (2.5M rows, seemingly small records) don't sound overly huge and the machine described seemed impressive, I wondered how bad this would run on my laptop. As such I created this test that 'simulates' the question:

```
IF DB_ID('test') IS NULL CREATE DATABASE test
GO
USE test
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

PRINT Convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 113) + ' - starting up, creating t_old_table...'

IF OBJECT_ID('t_old_table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE t_old_table

GO
CREATE TABLE t_old_table (row_id int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
                          document_id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, 
                          parsed_codes nvarchar(50) NOT NULL)
GO

PRINT Convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 113) + ' - starting up, creating docuemnt_id''s...'

-- create unique document_id's first
DECLARE @counter int = 1,
        @target  int = 500000,
        @block   int = 10000

INSERT t_old_table (document_id, parsed_codes) VALUES (Reverse(Convert(nvarchar(50), NewID())), Convert(nvarchar(50), BINARY_CHECKSUM(NewID())))

WHILE @counter < @target
    BEGIN
        INSERT t_old_table (document_id, parsed_codes) 
        SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN @counter + @block > @target THEN @target - @counter ELSE @block END)
               Reverse(Convert(nvarchar(50), NewID())), 
               Convert(nvarchar(50), BINARY_CHECKSUM(NewID()))
          FROM t_old_table

        SELECT @counter = @counter + @@ROWCOUNT
    END

PRINT Convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 113) + ' - starting up, adding parsed codes...'

-- add parsed-codes to existing document_id's
SELECT @target = @target * 5

WHILE @counter < @target
    BEGIN
        INSERT t_old_table (document_id, parsed_codes) 
        SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN @counter + @block > @target THEN @target - @counter ELSE @block END)
               document_id, 
               Convert(nvarchar(50), BINARY_CHECKSUM(NewID()))
          FROM t_old_table
         ORDER BY NewID() -- some document_id's will have more, some will have less

        SELECT @counter = @counter + @@ROWCOUNT
    END

UPDATE STATISTICS t_old_table

PRINT Convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 113) + ' - Creating t_new_table...'

GO
IF OBJECT_ID('t_new_table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE t_new_table
GO
CREATE TABLE t_new_table (document_id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                          parsed_codes_list nvarchar(max) NOT NULL)

GO
```

Running this took about 6 minutes on my (t)rusty i5 laptop

- 13 Mar 2015 22:20:09:053 - starting up, t_old_table...
- 13 Mar 2015 22:20:09:073 - starting up, creating docuemnt_id's...
- 13 Mar 2015 22:20:13:273 - starting up, adding parsed codes...
- 13 Mar 2015 22:26:27:023 - Creating t_new_table...

Next I took the following approach :

```
PRINT Convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 113) + ' - Creating #numbered table...'

-- step 1, make temp-table that holds 'correct' order
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#numbered') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #numbered
GO
SELECT document_id,
       parsed_codes,
       order_nbr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY document_id ORDER BY parsed_codes)
  INTO #numbered
  FROM t_old_table  
 WHERE 1 = 2

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uq0 ON #numbered (order_nbr, document_id)

INSERT #numbered
SELECT document_id,
       parsed_codes,
       order_nbr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY document_id ORDER BY parsed_codes )
  FROM t_old_table

GO
-- extract parsed codes
DECLARE @nbr int = 1,
        @rowcount int 

SET NOCOUNT OFF
PRINT Convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 113) + ' - Converting to t_new_table, step ' + convert(varchar, @nbr) + '...'

INSERT t_new_table (document_id, parsed_codes_list)
SELECT document_id, parsed_codes
  FROM #numbered
 WHERE order_nbr = @nbr

SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

UPDATE STATISTICS t_new_table

WHILE @rowcount > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @nbr = @nbr + 1

        PRINT Convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 113) + ' - Converting to t_new_table, step ' + convert(varchar, @nbr) + '...'

        UPDATE t_new_table
           SET parsed_codes_list = parsed_codes_list + ';' + n.parsed_codes
          FROM t_new_table
          JOIN #numbered n
            ON n.document_id = t_new_table.document_id
           AND n.order_nbr = @nbr

        SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
    END

GO

-- all done
PRINT Convert(varchar, current_timestamp, 113) + ' - All done.'
```

This does take quite some sorting up-front, but once things get looping, the joins are actually pretty straightforward and fast. In fact, the whole thing ran in less than a minute.

- 13 Mar 2015 22:26:27:030 - Creating #numbered table...
- 13 Mar 2015 22:26:41:307 - Converting to t_new_table, step 1...
- (500000 row(s) affected)
- 13 Mar 2015 22:26:45:543 - Converting to t_new_table, step 2...
- (400986 row(s) affected)
- 13 Mar 2015 22:26:49:863 - Converting to t_new_table, step 3...
- (322042 row(s) affected)
- [...]
- 13 Mar 2015 22:27:15:713 - Converting to t_new_table, step 62...
- (1 row(s) affected)
- 13 Mar 2015 22:27:15:900 - Converting to t_new_table, step 63...
- (0 row(s) affected)
- 13 Mar 2015 22:27:15:940 - All done.

Since I can't believe my laptop/solution being that  much faster than what you have, I ran your query

```
SELECT 
    t1.document_id as document_id,
    Stuff((SELECT '; ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), parsed_codes)
           FROM t_old_table t2
           WHERE t2.document_id = t1.document_id
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as [New_parsed_codes]
INTO dbo.[New_Table]
FROM t_old_table t1
GROUP BY t1.document_id
```

and it ran in 40 seconds.

This makes me believe you'll need to explain a bit further on the situation (size does matter =) so we can better grasp where the time is being spent; or you have a hardware issue ...